# sed (or awk): add a new line "commit;" after every n-th line but only if next line starts with pattern

Tags: awk, sed

I have a very large SQL file and would like to add a new line "commit;" every e.g. 100000 lines.

This would be easy, BUT the sql contains CLOBs and BLOBs with line breaks.

I need to make sure that the new line is not created in such rows.

In other words: I need to put a "commit;" every n-th line but only if next line starts with "INSERT INTO".

input:

```
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X .....foo bar
foo bar foo
bar foo
bar);
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X .....foo
bar
foo bar);
INSERT INTO X ..... );
```

expected output (for this example lets say add commit to every 2nd line):

```
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X ..... );
commit;
INSERT INTO X .....foo bar
foo bar foo
bar foo
bar);
INSERT INTO X ..... );
commit;
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X .....foo
bar
foo bar);
commit;
INSERT INTO xxx ..... );
```

Suggestions much appreciated :)

Comment: Couldn't that `foo bar` data itself contain `INSERT INTO X` at the beginning of the line?

Comment: Use a *real* scripting language. sed(1) is an *editor* thought as a way of extending the *line* editor ed(1) to work on huge files; awk(1) was designed to process files with one more or less fixed one line format records. Any much more complicated processing is just overtaxing the tool.

Comment: Are you assuming that the SQL only contains INSERT statements, no others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example to paste `commit` after every third INSERT.

```
sed '0~2{:a;N;/;$/!ba;s/$/\ncommit;/}'
```

I assume that every insert ends with `;` at the end of the line (you might need to add `\s*` after `;` if you have some lines with spaces in the end.

The logic is to grab 3 lines and check whether there is `;` at the end and concatenate more lines until it gets the line with `;` at the end. And insert `commit;` afterwards.

Once the line added it will proceed further with next lines.

Feel free to adjust a number of lines to your needs.

Comment: works perfect - thank you very much!

Comment: That doesn't produce the expected output posted in the question and it's not obvious how you'd modify it to do so.

Comment: @EdMorton to get the output exactly like in question you need to write `0~1` instead of `0~2` in sed statement.

Comment: I tried that first but it also doesn't produce the desired output (e.g. it adds a commit between the 3rd and 4th INSERT lines)

Answer (score 0):

A solution in `awk` that takes each group of `n` lines (`n = 3` in the example) and inserts a "commit;" before the last of the lines, provided it starts with "INSERT INTO" would be:

```
$ awk '{ if (/^INSERT INTO/ && NR%3 == 0) { print "commit;" }; print }' input
```

Comment: You can't use NR like that since the INSERT statements can span multiple lines and per the posted example the OP is actually looking to add a commit every N INSERT statements, not every N lines.

Comment: @EdMorton you're right, good catch.

Answer (score 0):

With any awk in any shell on every UNIX box and assuming you only have semi-colons at the end of lines when they're at the end of every INSERT statement like in your posted sample input:

```
$ awk '{print} /;$/ && !((++c)%2){print "commit;"}' file
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X ..... );
commit;
INSERT INTO X .....foo bar
foo bar foo
bar foo
bar);
INSERT INTO X ..... );
commit;
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X .....foo
bar
foo bar);
commit;
INSERT INTO X ..... );
```

---

Original answer when I was overthinking the problem:

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and assuming you only have semi-colons at the end of lines when they're at the end of every INSERT statement:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=";\n"} {print} !(NR%2){print "commit"}' file
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X ..... );
commit;
INSERT INTO X .....foo bar
foo bar foo
bar foo
bar);
INSERT INTO X ..... );
commit;
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X .....foo
bar
foo bar);
commit;
INSERT INTO X ..... );
```

Otherwise, with any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk '/^INSERT/{ if (c++ == 2) {print "commit;"; c=1} } {print} END{if (c == 2) print "commit;"}' file
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X ..... );
commit;
INSERT INTO X .....foo bar
foo bar foo
bar foo
bar);
INSERT INTO X ..... );
commit;
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X .....foo
bar
foo bar);
commit;
INSERT INTO X ..... );
```

You need the END section since it's inserting before the N+1th INSERT statement rather than after the Nth INSERT statement and you need to handle the case where there's exactly a multiple of N INSERTs in the input, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X .....foo bar
foo bar foo
bar foo
bar);
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X .....foo
bar
foo bar);
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X ..... );
```

Without the END statement we fail to add the final `commit;`:

```
$ awk '/^INSERT/{ if (c++ == 2) { print "commit;"; c=1 } } {print}' file
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X ..... );
commit;
INSERT INTO X .....foo bar
foo bar foo
bar foo
bar);
INSERT INTO X ..... );
commit;
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X .....foo
bar
foo bar);
commit;
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X ..... );
```

while with it we succeed:

```
$ awk '/^INSERT/{ if (c++ == 2) { print "commit;"; c=1 } } {print}; END{if (c == 2) print "commit;"}' file
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X ..... );
commit;
INSERT INTO X .....foo bar
foo bar foo
bar foo
bar);
INSERT INTO X ..... );
commit;
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X .....foo
bar
foo bar);
commit;
INSERT INTO X ..... );
INSERT INTO X ..... );
commit;
```

and of course if you just want a `commit;` after the final INSERT no matter how many are present then just remove the `if ( c == 2 )` from the END and leave the `print`.

Comment: I think your top solution adds a commit after every `n` statements, not just after the INSERTs. Maybe that was OP's intention though. It's obviously easily to adapt either way.